# How to delete files based on "Last Access Time" for Powershell 5.0 and beyond?

Tags: powershell-5.0

Been pulling my hair out for a couple days trying to understand why I cannot delete (or list) files using the Last Access Time  file attribute.   All examples I have found on the WWW return Last Write Time...  Despite passing  { $_.LastAccessTime }

I think it has to do with the examples being written in PowerShell 2.0.

For example,

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path c:\ | Where-Object {$_.LastAccessTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(1)}
```

Returns
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----

However, using

```
Select-Object -Property LastAccessTime, FullName
```

DOES Last Access Time but I don't know how to take that info and make PS delete it.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path c:\ | Select-Object -Property LastAccessTime, FullName
```

What I want is an updated script that works in PowerShell 5.0 (or whatever Windows 2016 uses), accepts 2 parameters --  PATH and DAYS and deletes them.

Bonus to have it first move the files to a folder instead of delete, such as Archive.   I will then run the same script later that can delete the files in the Archive folder.

I also have run FSUTIL (and rebooted) -

```
fsutil behavior set disablelastaccess 0
```

Comment: Don't use Select-Object. You need to pipe results to the Remove-Item or Move-Item.

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path c:\ | Where-Object {$_.LastAccessTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(1)} | Remove-Item

Comment: @fenixil This still returns LastWrtieTime,  not LastAccessTime despite asking for LastAccessTime

Comment: what `fsutil behavior query disableLastAccess` returns you? I tried it on my machine, it returns 2 and `LastAccessTime` is returned perfectly fine. Can you elaborate on your testing in the question, how do you verify that it returns LastWrtieTime but not LastAccessTime?